# OpenSuse 12.2 and drbd

Tags: linux, opensuse, mirroring, opensuse-12.2

I am trying to setup tow NFS servers mirrored by drbd using OpenSuse 12.2 x64.
There is a yast2 package for the drbd which I installed.

The module is found under yast2 - Mischellaneous.

I get the error message "Error while creating client module drbd".

Searching the internet gives a few other hits with people having the same problem back in 2008, but no real solution found.

Does anybody know the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use openSUSE, but why not try the package at http://software.opensuse.org/package/drbd#.  (It looks to me like there are 2 packages, a DRBD package and a yast2-drbd package.  I'm guessing you installed the wrong package ?)